# How to randomly select and click on element with selenium webdriver (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have to randomly select an element from todo list app and click to delete it. Basically, every element has the same selector, just index changes (e.g.//*[@class="destroy"])[2]).
I have code that generates random sentences and adds them to the app. Then I have to randomly select an element -> click on it to delete and here I got stuck. Random.choice selects a random number and actually, it works. But sometimes if it randomly selects [0] the test fails and test execution takes a lot of time and I believe there is a more professional way to make a random choice. Could you please advise other possible ways?

````
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import random
import os
 
@keyword
    def open_browser(self):
        os.environ['MOZ_HEADLESS'] = '1'
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get('http://todomvc.com/examples/react/#/')
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)
@keyword
    def generate_random_sentences(self, number, total_items_amount):
        words = [["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"], ["red", "yellow", "green", "blue"],
                 ["cats", "dogs", "zebras", "pandas"], ["jumped.", "danced.", "wrote poetry.", "cried."]]
        for i in range(int(number)):
            sentences = ' '.join([random.choice(w) for w in words])
            self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "new-todo").send_keys(sentences, Keys.ENTER)
        total_items = self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "todo-count")
        assert total_items.text == total_items_amount```

@keyword
    def delete_random_element(self, total_items_amount):
        i = random.choice(range(51))
        list_item = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//*[@class="view"]){}'.format([i])) 
        hidden_button = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//*[@class="destroy"]){}'.format([i])) 
        actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
        actions.move_to_element(list_item)
        actions.click(hidden_button)
        actions.perform()
        total_items = self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "todo-count")
        assert total_items.text == total_items_amount```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `random.randint(start, end)` to specify a range of integers that can be randomly selected and pass that as the index.

```
random_element = f'//*[@class="destroy"])[{random.randint(startint,endint)}]'
```